# How to ignore duplicate string?

Tags: python

I had some script below

```
unique=[]

thislist =['idn_type1=：111-22-3333',
'idn_type1=：111-22-3333',
'idn_type1=：222-33-4444',
'idn_type2=：333-44-5555',
'idn_type2=：222-33-4444',
'idn_type3=：222-33-4444',
'idn_type4=：222-33-4444',
'idn_type1=：',
'idn_type1=：444-55-6666',
'idn_type1=：555-66-7777',
'idn_type1=：']

for name in thislist:
      if name not in unique and name.partition('：')[-1] not in unique and name.partition('：')[-1]!='':
            unique.append(name)

for i in range(len(unique)):
    print(unique[i])
```

And the result is wrong

```
idn_type1=：111-22-3333
idn_type1=：222-33-4444
idn_type2=：333-44-5555
idn_type2=：222-33-4444
idn_type3=：222-33-4444
idn_type4=：222-33-4444
idn_type1=：444-55-6666
idn_type1=：555-66-7777
```

But what I want is

```
idn_type1=：111-22-3333
idn_type1=：222-33-4444
idn_type2=：333-44-5555
idn_type1=：444-55-6666
idn_type1=：555-66-7777
```

I want idn `'222-33-4444'` append only once when it meets first with `idn_type1`.
Only `idn_type1=：222-33-4444` appended to the new list.

How to modify this script?

Thank Mr.Martineau to correct my description!
https://stackoverflow.com/users/355230/martineau

Comment: You didn't insert what you want to check for into the list, namely `name.partition(...)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use set to remember the numbers you already saw

```
unique = []

thislist = ['idn_type1=：111-22-3333',
            'idn_type1=：111-22-3333',
            'idn_type1=：222-33-4444',
            'idn_type2=：333-44-5555',
            'idn_type2=：222-33-4444',
            'idn_type3=：222-33-4444',
            'idn_type4=：222-33-4444',
            'idn_type1=：',
            'idn_type1=：444-55-6666',
            'idn_type1=：555-66-7777',
            'idn_type1=：']

seen = set()
for name in thislist:
    numbers = name.partition('：')[-1]
    if name not in unique and numbers not in seen and numbers != '':
        unique.append(name)
        seen.add(numbers)

for i in range(len(unique)):
    print(unique[i])
```

output:

```
idn_type1=：111-22-3333
idn_type1=：222-33-4444
idn_type2=：333-44-5555
idn_type1=：444-55-6666
idn_type1=：555-66-7777
```

hope i could help, if you need me to clarify anything feel free to ask in the comments :)

Comment: i would appreciate it if you could mark my comment as the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

use set to remove duplicate elements in your list.

```
thislist =['idn_type1=：111-22-3333',
'idn_type1=：111-22-3333',
'idn_type1=：222-33-4444'
,
'idn_type2=：333-44-5555',
'idn_type2=：222-33-4444',
'idn_type3=：222-33-4444',
'idn_type4=：222-33-4444',
'idn_type1=：',
'idn_type1=：444-55-6666',
'idn_type1=：555-66-7777',
'idn_type1=：']

unique = list(set(thislist))

for each in unique:
    print(each)
```